# Can you link current events and the parsha

Tags: parashat-bereishit

[image]

So I saw this post circling online. What exactly would we say about this? Is it just something “cute”, or is it like a valid method of searching for connections between current events and the parsha? What do traditional sources say about this?

I know there’s questions on here about linking current events in general to the Parsha, so I guess my question is more about davka such a specific thing like the name of *one* person that got murdered

Comment: What does it mean for a method to be valid?

Comment: The previous Lubavitcher Rebbe would often quote the famous explanation of the Alter Rebbe (see for example Sefer HaSichos 5702) in saying that we need to "live with the parasha". Building on this concept, I would point out that the Shaloh HaKodesh, as quoted by Rav Daniel Glatstein  shlita (introduction to his new series: Davar Yafeh B'Ito) would say that "there is a time and place for everything".

Comment: The Shaloh writes: The common denominator of these three portions is their preoccupation with the relationship between Joseph and his brothers. In view of the fact that the holiday of Chanukah occurs during the weeks we read these portions, and in view of the well known rule by King Solomon in Kohelet that there is a time and place for everything, we will find in the timing of the various holidays ordained by the Rabbis or even the fast-days decreed by them, allusions to the subject matters dealt with in the portions of the Torah read during that respective week of the year.

Comment: Rav Daniel Glatstein also quotes Rav Moshe Wolfson in his sefer ["Emunas Itecha"][3] where he (supposedly) says that it is an idea of the Chozeh of Lublin that not only are the parshios connected to the time of the year, but the parsha will have an influence to the time of the year the parsha is read. For example, when reading parshas Yisro, you'll get the feel of Shavuos, when we got the Torah. When you read Beshalach, you'll have the feeling of Pesach etc..

Comment: The *Sefer Niphlaos MiToras Hashem Yisbarach* agrees with your suggested methodology. (https://seforimplace.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=7152)